# FactoryBeans and the annotation-based configuration in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-annotations

Spring provides the `FactoryBean` interface to allow non-trivial initialisation of beans. The framework provides many implementations of factory beans and -- when using Spring's XML config -- factory beans are easy to use.

However, in Spring 3.0, I can't find a satisfactory way of using factory beans with the  annotation-based configuration (née JavaConfig).

Obviously, I could manually instantiate the factory bean and set any required properties myself, like so:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

...

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setAnotherProperty(anotherProperty());

        return factory.getObject();
    }
```

However, this would fail if the `FactoryBean` implemented any Spring-specific callback interfaces, like `InitializingBean`, `ApplicationContextAware`, `BeanClassLoaderAware`, or `@PostConstruct` for example. I also need to inspect the FactoryBean, find out what callback interfaces it implements, then implement this functionality myself by calling `setApplicationContext`, `afterPropertiesSet()` etc.

This feels awkward and back-to-front to me: application-developers should not have to implement the callbacks of the IOC container.

Does anyone know of a better solution to using FactoryBeans from Spring Annotation configs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem is what you want a result of `sqlSessionFactory()` to be a `SqlSessionFactory` (for use in other methods), but you have to return `SqlSessionFactoryBean` from a `@Bean`-annotated method in order to trigger Spring callbacks.

It can be solved with the following workaround:

```
@Configuration 
public class AppConfig { 
    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean() { ... }

    // FactoryBean is hidden behind this method
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return sqlSessionFactoryBean().getObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AnotherBean anotherBean() {
        return new AnotherBean(sqlSessionFactory());
    }
}
```

The point is that calls to `@Bean`-annotated methods are intercepted by an aspect which performs initialization of the beans being returned (`FactoryBean` in your case), so that call to `sqlSessionFactoryBean()` in `sqlSessionFactory()` returns a fully initialized `FactoryBean`.

Comment: But i cant understand where is the profit of using FactoryBean. Because in that case we can simple create regular bean with Static factory which will return a bean and result will be the same.

Answer (score 22):

I think that this is best solved when you rely on auto-wiring. If you are using Java configuration for the beans, this would like:

```
@Bean
MyFactoryBean myFactory()
{ 
    // this is a spring FactoryBean for MyBean
    // i.e. something that implements FactoryBean<MyBean>
    return new MyFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
MyOtherBean myOther(final MyBean myBean)
{
    return new MyOtherBean(myBean);
}
```

So Spring will inject for us the MyBean instance returned by the myFactory().getObject() as it does with XML configuration.

This should also work if you are using @Inject/@Autowire in your @Component/@Service etc classes.

Comment: Do 'MyBean' instance will be the same every time we inject it somewhere or for every injection factory will create new instance?

Comment: @KonstantinZyubin It depends how do you implement the [isSingleton](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html#isSingleton--) method.

Answer (score 5):

Spring JavaConfig had a [ConfigurationSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/apidocs/org/springframework/config/java/support/ConfigurationSupport.html) class that had a getObject() method for use with FactoryBean's.

You would use it be extending

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends ConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public MyBean getMyBean() {
       MyFactoryBean factory = new MyFactoryBean();
       return (MyBean) getObject(factory);
    }
}
```

There is some background in this [jira issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SJC-145)

With Spring 3.0 JavaConfig was moved into Spring core and it was decided to get rid of the [ConfigurationSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/apidocs/org/springframework/config/java/support/ConfigurationSupport.html) class. Suggested approach is to now use builder pattern instead of factories.

An example taken from the new [SessionFactoryBuilder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/SessionFactoryBuilder.html)

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactoryBean()
           .setDataSource(dataSource())
           .setMappingLocations("classpath:com/myco/*.hbm.xml"})
           .buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Some background [here](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/use-of-factorybeans-with-spring-javaconfig)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm doing, and it works:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() { // Automatically configured from a properties file
    return new BasicDataSource();
}

@Bean
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource); // Invoking dataSource() would get a new instance which won't be initialized
    factory.setAnotherProperty(anotherProperty());
    return factory;
}


@Bean
public AnotherBean anotherBean(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) { // This method receives the SqlSessionFactory created by the factory above
    return new AnotherBean(sqlSessionFactory);
}
```

Any bean you have declared can be passed as an argument to any other @Bean method (invoking the same method again will create a new instance which is not processed by spring).
If you declare a FactoryBean, you can use the bean type it creates as an argument for another @Bean method, and it will receive the right instance.
You could also use

```
@Autowired
private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;
```

Anywhere and it will work too.

Comment: Would you like to create every time a new Instance of SQl session when you will launch sqlSessionFactory ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not inject the Factory in your AppConfiguration?

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Resource
    private SqlSessionFactoryBean factory;

    @Bean 
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
       return factory.getObjectfactory();    
    }    
}
```

*But may I did not understand your question correct. Because it looks to me that you are trying something strange -  go a step back and rethink what are you really need.*

Comment: Ralph, thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work, as the FactoryBean (in this example, SqlSessionFactoryBean, but it could be _anything_ that implements `org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean` - for example  `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`) is not under my control (or in my source) and isn't annotated with @Value/@Resource/@Autowired/@Inject annotations. Therefore Spring won't inject it's dependencies properly before I call `.getObject()` on it.

Comment: @Andrew Newdigate -- the factory itself is a candidate for XML configuration, or if you do not like XML then create it in an other @Bean annotated method. (then you can use @Value)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing it:

```
@Bean
def sessionFactoryBean: AnnotationSessionFactoryBean = {
  val sfb = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

  sfb.setDataSource(dataSource)
  sfb.setPackagesToScan(Array("com.foo.domain"))

  // Other configuration of session factory bean
  // ...

  return sfb
}

@Bean
def sessionFactory: SessionFactory = {
   return sessionFactoryBean.getObject
}
```

The sessionFactoryBean gets created and the proper post-create lifecycle stuff happens to it (afterPropertiesSet, etc).

Note that I do not reference the sessionFactoryBean as a bean directly.   I autowire the sessionFactory into my other beans.