# How to retrieve JNDI using Spring @Configuration instead of XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I've started development of a new Spring 3.2.4 application and am trying to use Java based configuration instead of XML files as I have used in the past.  However, I am having trouble making the transition.

Using XML, I would code it as follows:

```
<!-- application datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource.jndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/liment" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource.jndi"/>
</bean>
```

However, I am very much stuck trying to figure out how to do this in Java.  I'm trying to replicate the configuration, but running into trouble:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.ia"})
public class AppConfigJPA {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // configure and return the necessary JDBC DataSource
        JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        dataSource.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/liment");
        try {
            dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NamingException e) {
            // rethrow
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return (DataSource)dataSource.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
            emf.afterPropertiesSet
        return emf.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.setBeanFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 33 more
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

***EDIT***

Following @SotiriosDelimanolis response, I have modified my code to read the following:

```
@Autowired DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource() {
    // configure and return the necessary JDBC DataSource
    JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    dataSource.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/josak");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return emf;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

But am getting Autowired exceptions instead now:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource com.ia.system.configuration.AppConfigJPA.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Can you verify that the reference returned by `dataSource.getObject();` is `null`? That shouldn't happen if you called `afterPropertiesSet()`. And please post the longer stack trace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Actually, I just caught a mistake in the code before I saw your comment.  I had forgotten an "afterPropertiesSet()" call in the entityManagerFactory().  But now, I get a different Exception relating to a persistence exception translator.

Answer (score 25):

please refer below link -

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/724356-how-to-use-javaconfig-to-declare-a-jndi-datasource

the datasource need to be created like this  -

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/yourJdbcGoesHere");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: `setResourceRef` is not necessary in this context as JndiDataSourceLookup sets it to true. The code is simply `new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("jdbc/yourJdbcGoesHere")`

Comment: You should actually use @Bean(destroyMethod="")

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird design (for `PersistenceExceptionTranslator`) that I don't immediately understand, but here is the solution.

Your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is a `FactoryBean` but also a `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` (implements both). But you aren't putting the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` into your context, you are only getting its created object.

Instead of

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emf.afterPropertiesSet
    return emf.getObject();
}
```

do

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return emf;
}

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

Spring will take care of calling `afterPropertiesSet()` and `getObject()` to put a `EntityManagerFactory` bean into the context.

Basically you end up with two beans, a `EntityManagerFactory` and a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Your JPA configuration requires a `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` bean in the context. That will be satisfied by `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

---

FYI, you can do the same thing for your `JndiObjectFactoryBean` or any other `FactoryBean`.

Comment: The JpaTransactionManager is expecting an EntityManagerFactory as its constructor type.  If entityManagerFactory() returns a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, how do I instantiate the transactionManager()?  Similarly, if I return a JndiObjectFactoryBean from dataSource(), how do I set the emf.setDataSource() with teh JndiFactoryBean?

Comment: @EricB. Spring is magic that way. It proxies the `@Bean` method calls and returns the `FactoryBean` created bean instead of the `FactoryBean` itself.

Comment: I don't understand.  Returning the factory bean makes the compiler complain on `return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory())` : `The constructor JpaTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) is 
 undefined`

Comment: @EricB. Oh that. My bad. A workaround is to `@Autowired` beans of the type of object your `FactoryBean` beans create into some `@Configuration` class fields. Then use them instead of calling their respective methods.

Comment: This seems very complicated.  Can you post an example please?  I tried what you suggested, but obviously am doing something wrong as I am getting NoSuchBeanDefnExceptions when it is trying to autowire my DataSource bean.  I'm editing the question above to post my new code and exception

Comment: Thanks for the update, but still no dice.  I'm getting circular bean referencing errors: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?`

Comment: @ericB. At worst, you can call the `@Bean` methods and call the `getObject()` method on their returned references. You will have to cast the return value of `JndiObjectFactoryBean`. [Something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541094/factorybeans-and-the-annotation-based-configuration-in-spring-3-0). A `FactoryBean` is typically meant to return the same instance on each call.