# How to create datasource with JNDI link (Wildfly)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly-10

How I can connect to database with JTA and without persistence.xml, use only annotations?
And how create datasource with JNDI link ?

I have JNDI link from Wildfly_10 java:jboss/datasources/PostgreDataSource

persistence.xml snippet

```
    `<persistence-unit name="Unit1" transaction-type="JTA"> 
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreDataSource</jta-data-source> 
        <properties> 
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
        </properties> 
    </persistence-unit>`
```

My config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "net.myProg" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.myProg.repository")
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("net.myProg.model");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
//        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        //Lazy load initializayion. Hibernate сам открывает сессию для получения lazy объекта, если это нужно
        properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"));
//        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return db;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find answer here [How to use JNDI DataSource provided by Tomcat in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring)

@Configuration
public class MainConfig {

```
...

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
    try {
        dataSource = jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/yourname", DataSource.class);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("NamingException for java:comp/env/jdbc/yourname", e);
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Create a bean for data source using jndi name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache
        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/cache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="appDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:jboss/datasources/xyzDataSouce</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

If your Using a JPA Repository can use this Data Source like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache
        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/cache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">        

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="apptransactionManager" />

    <bean id="apptransactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="appEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="appEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
              <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>net.something.something</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${jpaVendorAdapter.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jpaVendorAdapter.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${jpaVendorAdapter.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${jpaVendorAdapter.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${jpaVendorAdapter.hibernate.default_schema}</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">${jpaVendorAdapter.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix}</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix">${jpaVendorAdapter.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix}</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">${jpaVendorAdapter.org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name}</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">${jpaVendorAdapter.org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name}</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.something.something.core.dao" transaction-manager-ref="apptransactionManager"/>         

    <!-- Needed for @PersistenceContext annotation -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" /> 

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="apptransactionManager"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <!-- JSR-303 bean validation -->
    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <!-- <property name="providerClass" value="org.apache.bval.jsr303.ApacheValidationProvider" /> -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

If you want you can create two files and add those two files into application-context xml and everything will start working fine

Comment: This is not annotations only. You have xml config files.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431517/how-to-retrieve-jndi-using-spring-configuration-instead-of-xml-configuration