# Register spring bean as an apache camel route builder with java config

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-java-config

[apache camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/spring.html) describes how to register a route builder with @Component and SpringRouteBuilder and then jumps to the xml code to do

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <!-- and then let Camel use those @Component scanned route builders -->
  <contextScan/>
</camelContext>
```

How can I do the same with java config? I've got

```
package x.y.camel;
@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {...}
```

and

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"x.y"})
public class Application implements WebApplicationInitializer {
   @Bean
   public SpringCamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
    SpringCamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
    return camelContext;
   }
```

The component is picked up by spring and created, that part is fine. I can register the route by `camelContext.addRoutes(new MyRouteBuilder());`. The only bit is missing is how to tell camel context to pick up the route if it's managed as a spring bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was pretty close to the solution. All I had to do is to add a ComponentScan annotation on my CamelConfiguration class that I already had.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("x.y.camel")
public class CamelConfig extends CamelConfiguration {
}
```

And then remove `public SpringCamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)` from my Application class.

That's it - the RouteBuilder is picked up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach does not work, because you don't create your camel context with the [CamelContextFactoryBean](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.14.0/camel-spring/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spring/CamelContextFactoryBean.html). This is where the logic is hidden that looks for Spring Bean Camel Routes in your classpath.

The easiest solution to the problem is to add a xml-based Spring context configuration that references this factory bean!

Alternatively, you can try calling the factory bean from your *Application class* (see this link: [FactoryBeans and the annotation-based configuration in Spring 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541094/factorybeans-and-the-annotation-based-configuration-in-spring-3-0?rq=1)), but calling a factory bean from a `@Configuration` class is tricky, because they are both part of mechanisms that are not build for compatibility. Especially, since `CamelContextFactoryBean` is also implementing `InitialisingBean`.

Comment: Thanks Fritz, your answer pushed me in the right direction. It turns out you can do that without a xml configuration. See my answer. Wish it was better documented somewhere.